# Inner product and its conjugate

Tags: inner-products

How do I prove $\langle x,y \rangle$=$\overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$ using polarization identity

Comment: I think it's not true as currently written; for example $\langle i,i\rangle=i(-i)=1,$ whereas $\langle\overline i,i\rangle=(-i)(-i)=-1$

Comment: What do you mean by $<xy>$?

Comment: $\bar{<xy>}$ corrected to $\bar{<yx>}$

Comment: Do you mean $\langle x,y \rangle$ when you type $<xy>$?

Comment: Use `\overline` rather than `\bar` (except for single letters, and even then only for narrow ones $\overline{w}$ is better than $\bar{w}$).

Comment: But what does $xy$ mean?  Does the underlying space have a product structure?  If what you meant to ask was $<x,y>=\overline {<y,x>}$ then that is one of the standard axioms concerning an inner product over a complex space...is that what you meant?

Comment: @W Tanner. Yes that’s what I mean but could not get that symbol.  @ Daniel Fischer. Thank you corrected to \overline

Comment: @ lulu. Yes that’s what I mean and my textbook does not have a proof of that axiom (Functional Analysis by BV Limaye, page 368 - conjugate symetry)

Comment: You can't prove an axiom.  It's part of the definition.  If you intended a non-standard definition, you have to provide that.  [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) is the standard definition...the property you want is axion $\#5$.

Comment: @SAK:      I used `\langle` to get "$\langle$" and `\rangle` to get "$\rangle$" and put a regular comma between $x$ and $y$

Comment: @lulu ok  thanks was trying to prove it using polarization identity but could not succeed

Comment: @ Tanner thank you corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_complex_scalars)$$\langle x,\,y\rangle=\frac14(\Vert x+y\Vert^2-\Vert x-y\Vert^2+i\Vert x-iy\Vert^2-i\Vert x+iy\Vert^2),$$we have$$\overline{\langle y,\,x\rangle}=\frac14(\Vert x+y\Vert^2-\Vert y-x\Vert^2-i\Vert y-ix\Vert^2+i\Vert y+ix\Vert^2).$$Since $\Vert iz\Vert^2=\Vert z\Vert^2$,$$\overline{\langle y,\,x\rangle}=\frac14(\Vert x+y\Vert^2-\Vert x-y\Vert^2-i\Vert x+iy\Vert^2+i\Vert x-iy\Vert^2)=\langle x,\,y\rangle.$$